# How to install Redis DeskTop manager for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, redis, desktop-application

Can somebody suggest how to install redis desktop manager in ubuntu 14.04?

I want to use for python application. While I'm cloning from github, it's asking username and password, but I don't have such credentials. And when I'm installing by downloading zip file, it's not installing.

So please suggest some effective way.

Comment: how you installed? did you download package deb file and installed using ubuntu package manager?

Answer (score 0):

> how to install redis desktop manager in ubuntu 14.04?
>   Just follow the link for [installing in ubuntu.](http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/install/).

**Ubuntu:**

- Download deb package from http://redisdesktop.com/download (Requires subscription)
- Install package via Ubuntu Software Center
- Run RedisDesktopManager :  /usr/share/redis-desktop-manager/bin/rdm or  redis-desktop-manager

These steps copied as-is from the [link](http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/install/) I provided.

> While I'm cloning from github, it's asking username and password, but I d'nt have any such credentials.

- to create your credentials it is easy.
- Go to github site. https://github.com/join?source=header-home
- Click on sighup.
- fill the form, `username`, `valid email`, `password`. and Submit.
- use the same creds for cloning the repo.

> And when I'm installing by downloading zip file, it's not installing.

- Please download the deb-file, and install via `ubuntu software center`

Comment: @mxdel please post specific error-details, if you face installation error, after following above steps from above given [link](http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/install/).

Comment: The below error is coming when I'm clonning from github.  
"Clone of 'https://github.com/uglide/qgamp.git' into submodule path '3rdparty/qgamp' failed"

Comment: Can you tell the steps to install and run?

Comment: I could not open the url you gave `github.com/uglide/qgamp.git'`. I could see the same qgamp repo in different link `https://github.com/achipa/qgamp`. If you want to clone repo, then please go to url, and click the `Clone or download` button, you will get the url like `https://github.com/achipa/qgamp.git`. then just do `git clone https://github.com/achipa/qgamp.git`